# Swiper not working after the first initializing

Tags: html-framework-7, swiper.js

I am working on framework7 to build IOS cooking recipes app. so in the recipe page there is swiper for more recipes and it is working fine if you enter the page for the first time but if you click on one of the recipes the swiper not working in the new page

here is the code to generate the page

```
    $$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="single"]', function (e,page) {
    var url3=xxx;
    app.request.get(url3, function (data3) {
    $.each(JSON.parse(data3), function(i3, item3) {
    $("div#alsolike").append('<div class="swiper-slide"> <a href="#" data-href="/single/'+item3.nid+'/"><div class="card"> <img class="card-image" src="'+item3.field_image+'" alt=""><div class="card-infos"><h2 class="card-title">'+item3.title+'</h2></div></div></a> </div>')
    })
    var rpSwiper = new Swiper ('#single-swiper', Object.assign({},swiperOptions, {width: 280}));
    })
    });
```

there is no error, I tried rpSwiper.update() but it showed error  "rpSwiper undefined  "

Comment: Where are you calling `rpSwiper.update()`? Inside the same scope as where you declare it?

Comment: @BrettGregson I tried to add it after the loop

Comment: So directly after where you declare it? (`var rpSwiper =...`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
var rpSwiper = new Swiper ('div#single-swiper', Object.assign({},swiperOptions, {width: 280}));
```